# AVPlayer not playing video in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, avplayer

Am trying to play a video in iOS 8, my code works fine in iOS 7 not in ios 8

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.view.layer addSublayer: layer];

[self.avPlayer play];
```

Comment: Do you hear some audio?

Comment: no it just shows a black screen, no audio nothing

Comment: in my case, I do hear some audio, but no video :/